# Not respond on willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Tags: ios6

I have in code

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: toInterfaceOrientation duration: duration];
    deviceOrientation = toInterfaceOrientation;
    if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        curPageSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);      
    }
    else if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        curPageSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);
    }
    [self correctViews:curPageSize];
}
```

this methods are defined in ModalViewController...
When i Rotate the device, program is not respond to willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration...

What should i do?!

Answer (score 1):

Try adapting your code to something like this...I have used this method in many Apps with success.  Happy coding!

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Landscape
        self.ViewL.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 728);
        self.ViewL.hidden=NO;
        self.ViewP.hidden=YES;

    }
    else
    {
        //Portrait
        self.ViewP.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 955);
        self.ViewP.hidden=NO;
        self.ViewL.hidden=YES;

    }
}
```